# Apparent Quarkus OpenAPI generation bug regarding allOf

Tags: quarkus, openapi-generator

Using Quarkus 3.3.3 and 3.6.1 (I assume all versions) using quarkus-smallrye-openapi generates incorrect OpenAPI specification in certain cases.

The issue/bug occurs when I add @Schema(description = "Some description.") to a custom object field member.  It does not occur for basic Java types such as String, Integer, etc.  But it does occur for custom enums I have defined, custom objects I have defined.

The bug is that with the addition of the schema field description it changes the field definition to be an allOf list member.  E.g. Adding the schema field description causes the generated OpenAPI to be like this:

```
ingestionType:
  description: Enum of the of the file ingestion options.
  type: string
  allOf:
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/EIngestionType'
```

Without the schema field description it generates the correct OpenAPI spec:

```
ingestionType:
  $ref: '#/components/schemas/EIngestionType'
```

The same behavior occurs for all custom object types.

How can we disable the generation of the allOf part?  allOf is a very strange addition to OpenAPI and it is rarely used or useful.  Here it completely breaks our spec and even the Swagger UI can't show the referenced type EIngestionType when allOf is used.

Thanks,
-David

Comment: Hello @user1340123, this is expected behavior. Since `$ref` cannot appear with any other properties in a schema, the `allOf` is used to apply the schema contraints from the referenced schema. What is the problem you are seeing in Swagger UI? I've tested a similar scenario without any issues.

Comment: Were is 'Since $ref cannot appear with any other properties in a schema, the allOf is used...?  If true that is unfortunate as it makes documenting schemas by adding Schema descriptions very error prone.  It works fine for basic types Strings, Integers, but one has to now know that they can't document custom object types at the field where they are defined.  Also can't Schema document JDK types like LocalDateTime either else OpenAPI adds the allOf.  Using allOf won't generate good client OpenAPI proxies for all languages that I use or am aware of as its a construct that is not supported.

Comment: Here is the documentation for OpenAPI 3.0.3 regarding a reference object (i.e. the object containing a `$ref`: https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3.html#reference-object). The example output you gave that includes an `allOf` should work with Swagger UI, so there may be a separate issue. I agree that code generation is a challenge, mainly due to the fact that JSON Schema is primarily intended for validation and does not always cleanly map to programming language structures.

Comment: As I read that spec it just says 'This object cannot be extended with additional properties and any properties added SHALL be ignored.'  I'm not asking to extend the object or add new properties.  All I want to do is add documentation of the existing reference-object which is exactly what I can do with basic types, strings, integers, etc.  What I can't tolerate is the addition of allOf just because I wanted to document a field.  Regarding your comment that 'JSON Schema is primarily intended for validation' that too is a shame as the OpenAPI spec should be designed for client generation IHMO.